# Lock record in database table

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a multi user database system.

I would like to know if there is a way so that only one user can view/edit 1 record at once.

When I say view/edit 1 record, I mean open the form which contains the records fields on it. If another user tries to go into the same record they will be prompted with a message and wont let them in until the other user has closed out of it.

Connecting to database via datasource, TadQuery (fireDAC).

Thanks,

Comment: Read this http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html

Comment: Sir Rufo - I'm not sure that is helpful... the OP seems well aware of the pattern since it is exactly what is asked for, albeit using plain English.  It seems to me that what he wants is guidance on implementing the pattern, not the EA Consultant Approved name to use for it.

Comment: @Deltics What part of the question makes you feel he is well aware of this pattern? Nearly every customer without knowledge of programming could describe this expected behaviour.